# PHP looping through a nested array.. BUT:

Tags: php

I have an array with 3 values: time, sensor1, sensor2

Each of those 3 contain the exact same ammount of additional values.

I would like to loop through a specific one, for example time and only get those values.

I recon with foreach I would have to go through all of the 3?
Something like this (it didnt work it seems, thats why im asking):

```
foreach($datacollection as $valuearray)
    {
    $string .= "'" . $valuearray['time'] . "',";
    }
```

I hope you understand what I'd like to do!

Comment: Add your input array and desired output

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to output JSON using string functions? If yes, don't do that and use `json_encode()` instead!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try:

```
foreach ($datacollection['time'] as $value) {
    echo 'value is ' . $value;
}
```

is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.. stupid me!

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
foreach($datacollection as $value)
{ 
    $string[]= $value['time'];
}
print_r($string);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($datacollection['time'] as $valuearray) {

    foreach ($valuearray as $value){
        echo 'value: '.$value;
    }

}
```